# Using an enum variable as a class data member gives an error

Tags: c++

**VERSION-1:**

```
// In this, the enum is declared globally

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum Hand {RIGHT,LEFT};

class Batsman {
    public:
        Batsman(string s, Hand h) {
            name = s;
            hand = h; 
        }
        void setName(string s) {
            name = s;
        }
        void setHand(Hand h) {
            hand = h;
        }
        string getName() {
            return name;
        }
        Hand getHand() {
            return hand;
        }           
    private:
        string name;
        Hand hand;  
};

void main() {
    Batsman B1("Ryder",LEFT);
    Batsman B2("McCullum",RIGHT);
}
```

**VERSION-2:**

```
// In this, the enum is declared inside the class

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Batsman {
    public:     
        enum Hand {RIGHT,LEFT};
        Batsman(string s, Hand h) {
            name = s;
            hand = h; 
        }
        void setName(string s) {
            name = s;
        }
        void setHand(Hand h) {
            hand = h;
        }
        string getName() {
            return name;
        }
        Hand getHand() {
            return hand;
        }           
    private:
        string name;
        Hand hand;  
};

void main() {
    Batsman B1("Ryder",LEFT);
    Batsman B2("McCullum",RIGHT);
}
```

Errors:

```
D:\\Work Space\\C++\\C.cpp: In function `int main(...)':
D:\\Work Space\\C++\\C.cpp:33: `LEFT' undeclared (first use this function)
D:\\Work Space\\C++\\C.cpp:33: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
D:\\Work Space\\C++\\C.cpp:33: for each function it appears in.)
D:\\Work Space\\C++\\C.cpp:34: `RIGHT' undeclared (first use this function)
```

**Please kindly tell me the corrections in both the instances so that I can understand the concept once and for all. Will be really appreciated.**

Comment: "Errors"? Make sure you specify the exact error messages.

Comment: Add the errors that are produced... we are not compilers.

Comment: Why don't you pass and return those strings by const reference so you are not copying them all the time?

Comment: @AnonymousAndy Your edit was bad, the way it was done. You actually invalidated the existing answers.

Comment: @Neil Kirk:  I can understand 70% of what you've been trying to say. Can you please illustrate?

Comment: Yes, the first one works, that's why I edited it out, sorry.

Comment: `void setName(const string& s)` and `const string& getName() const` The latter is allowed as you are not returning a reference to a local variable (bad) but a member variable.

Answer (score 6):

For your 1st case, the code [compiles just fine for me](http://ideone.com/BT5x5a) (after fixing `main()`'s return type). I don't know which *errors* you're bothering about.

---

For your 2nd case, the enum is declared in scope of the class

```
class Batsman {
public:     
    enum Hand {RIGHT,LEFT};
    // ...
};
```

so you'll have to provide the scope qualifier in `main()`:

```
int main() {
    Batsman B1("Ryder",Batsman::LEFT);
                    // ^^^^^^^^^
    Batsman B2("McCullum",Batsman::RIGHT);
                       // ^^^^^^^^^
}
```

---

<sub>Also note you always should have `int` as return type of `main()`.</sub>

Comment: What???? I thought the return type of main was arbitrary. Any particular use of returning int instead of void?

Comment: @AnonymousAndy That is how main communicates success or error to the system

Comment: @AnonymousAndy _"What???? I thought the return type of main was arbitrary."_ Nope! It is (and always was) `int` according standard definitions.

Comment: Wow, I've been learning C++ for months and now, I came to know this. I'm glad and thankful to you guys for this and also mad at my instructors at the same time.

Comment: God damn it, this is why I love this site!

Comment: Actually return code from the main is pretty important (mostly in the *nix world that is but also in Windows). Based on its value you can determine how the application exited (that is if it didn't break during execution). You can get the return code of all the Linux tools that one loves using inside the terminal. Grep for example returns 0 as a return code if no match was found. Test this by typing "grep SOMETHING SOMEWHERE" and after that echoing its value "echo $?". These codes are essential for error handling between processes.